# Mysql Full Join (Unknown column in field list)

Tags: mysql

I always got an error from mysql my syntax is:

SELECT n.id, n.name, s.Surname, s.Gender FROM name FULL JOIN Surname ON n.id = s.id;

(i was doing full join)  help me

Comment: Full join is not present in MySQL

Comment: `FULL JOIN`s are not supported by MySQL. See [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified variables(alias names) "n" and "s". please add them after the table names and then try.

Comment: Just this suggestion alone won't fix the problem.

Comment: i already used a specify term but then i got it wrong also